# cpanel aumentar el uso del espacio en disco

Tags: cpanel

Estoy usando Cpanel para controlar varios dominios y quiero subir una pagina nueva a uno de los sitios, pero me dice que no hay espacio suficiente en el disco, como hago para aumentar el espacio en disco? se que si tengo mas espacio en el hosting porque otros sitios dentro de mi cpanel tienen un limite mayor de hasta 6gb.

alguien podría ayudarme?

[image: esto es lo que estoy viendo en cpanel, quiero aumentar de 100mb a 700mb]

Comment: Me temo que desde aquí no podemos ayudarte. O bien borra los archivos que no estés usando... o bien contrata más espacio en el hosting. Actualmente tú puedes tener todo lo que sean fotos, archivos multimedia, etc fuera del hosting, por decir algo, las fotos puedes tenerlas en Flickr en Dropbox, o en cualquier otro lugar y presentarlas en tu sitio. Lo mismo los documentos, PDFs, los puedes tener en Google Drive por ejemplo. O sea, necesitas establecer tu propio plan de administración de contenido... o pagar más, eso depende de ti y del bolsillo.

Comment: Por ejemplo [aquí](http://www.deiverbum.org/nueva-edicion-del-misal-y-nuevos-leccionarios-en-castellano/) las imágenes están en Flickr, no me ocupan espacio en el hosting. Y [aquí](http://www.deiverbum.org/directorio-homiletico-de-la-congregacion-para-el-culto-divino/) tanto imágenes como documentos están fuera del hosting también. Actualmente tú puedes prescindir hasta de la base de datos, y tener tus datos en una hoja de Google Sheets... y hasta hacerla funcionar como una base de datos... todo totalmente gratis.